# Does dying at the tower affect the bounties?

Tags: destiny

So say you have the **Body Dropper** bounty and you have 50/100 of the kills required to complete that bounty. And now say that you jump off the edge of the Tower on Earth.
Will it reset your bounty progress, or does it only reset if you die in the field?

Comment: As I recall, it resets it, but I would have to double check.  Interestingly, dying in PvP does not reset PvE "do x y times without dying" bounties.

Comment: Must jump on to try this.

Comment: @Namfuak As I recall dying in the Tower does not reset such bounties, just like deaths in the Crucible don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  Dying affects all bounties that hold the prerequisite of not dying or taking damage, like commented above, this excludes PvP, since PvP is not PK or Open World/Duel enabled at this time.

Comment: I don't follow the "since PvP is not PK or Open World/Duel enabled at this time" bit. I understand that deaths in PvP don't count and I'm happy with this being just because but I'm not sure what the last bit means or why it is relevant to why PvP deaths don't count...